# Getting error 401 (Unauthorized) when trying to fetch data

Tags: c#, vue.js, unauthorized

I am building this small project with C# and Vue.First I had CORS problems (blocked CORS)and I fixed it by adding

```
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
```

In my Web.config,But now I get GET http://localhost:27235/api/lookup 401 (Unauthorized) when I am trying to fetch data from Vue.

Comment: that does not seem like a CORS problem, but like a missing authorization. what authorization method is the app using? basic/oauth/...?  looks like the authorization headers in the request are missing or incorrect, or the permission not granted on the server side

Comment: yes basic auth,just a token to log in and you become instantly admin

Comment: and is the authorization header present in the failing request?  should be something like a header called _Authorization_ with a content like _dGVzdHVzZXI6dGVzdHB3ZA==_ (for testuser:testpwd).

do you maybe have a login page that gives you a bearer token? (https://archive.smashing.media/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/65e9dec2-7442-4946-af09-4a701475e2d0/auth-diagram.png)

Comment: no I dont have any of that,i have a hardcoded token(password)

Comment: No,the token is hardcoded in appsettings.json

Comment: can you post the code part where you set off the http request?

Comment: const data = fetch("http://localhost:27235/api/lookup");
i also found this in the c# using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

Comment: I tried changing the   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, AuthorizationLevel to Anonymous but it doesnt work

Comment: this is not a CORS issue, you have an authentication on app and request does not have proper values such as api key, username & password.